# How do I install Net::Pcap for Strawberry Perl in Windows 7?

Tags: perl, perl-module, winpcap, strawberry-perl

I try to install [Net::Pcap](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aPcap) in Windows, but it gives the following error messages:

```
c:\P P> cpan
cpan> install Net::Pcap

socket.h patched... ok
looking for -lwpcap... yes
checking for pcap_lib_version() in -lwpcap... no
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
You appear to lack the WinPcap developer pack.

If it is installed in a non-standard location, please try setting the LIBS
and INC values on the command line.  For instance, if you have unziped the
developer's pack in C:\WpdPack, you should execute:

    perl Makefile.PL INC=-IC:/WpdPack/Include "LIBS=-LC:/WpdPack/Lib -lwpcap"

Or get and install the WinPcap developer's pack from
  http://www.winpcap.org/install/
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
detecting available functions... ok

Checking if your kit is complete...

Looks good

Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lwpcap
```

How do I solve this problem? I have not installed any WinPcap developer pack; but I do have Wireshark installed.

Comment: so, you need WinPcap developer pack. get it from http://www.winpcap.org/install/ :) the "pack" contains the needed libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CPAN installation diagnostics explain your problem very clearly

> You appear to lack the WinPcap developer pack

They also tell you where to download them from

> Or get and install the WinPcap developer's pack from
>   http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm

Comment: -I reinstalled using above link but, it gives the same error.

Comment: The Installed the Developer Pack still it gaves the same error. PCAP is crapped